# converting react native android to react native web @react-native-picker/picker error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker, react-native-web

I am trying to convert my react-native android app into a react-native web app. While doing this I got an error in @react-native-picker\picker.

**Failed to compile**

./node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker/js/PickerIOS.js

Attempted import error: 'UnimplementedView' is not exported from 'react-native'.

how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you added @react-native-picker to your webpack config?